# Sending custom text notifications to users on Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have spent quite a long time trying to figure out if I can send custom activity notifications using the graph API and I have come across the 'POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/teamwork/sendActivityNotification'](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserId%7D/teamwork/sendActivityNotification%27) endpoint which seems to allow me to do what I want, however I get this error whenever I try it.

Any idea on what it could be and if what I want to do is at all possible?

[Screenshot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFFEo.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please refer to the below sample and check if helps: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/csharp

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are still facing the issue or its resolved?